# Scala Generic Function isInstanceOf[T] not working

Tags: scala, generics

I am using scala to check if a variable is an instance of a generic type using the following function

```
def has[StructureType <: UnfoundStructure]
(implicit t: ClassTag[StructureType]): Boolean = {
    println("HAS")
    println(struct)
    println(struct.isInstanceOf[Road])
    println(classTag[StructureType].runtimeClass)
    println(struct.isInstanceOf[StructureType])
    struct.isInstanceOf[StructureType]
}
```

The class Road extends UnfoundStructure but when I call has[Road] on something that has a City as its struct (another child of UnfoundStructure) it returns true! This is despite the fact that struct.isInstanceOf[Road] returns false. This is the output of the function:

```
HAS
City name Test City at 26,7 //Custom toString of the City type
false //struct.isInstanceOf[Road]
class com.vogon101.game.structures.Road //The runtime class of StructureType
true //struct.isInstanceOf[StructureType]
```

This function is called in, among other places, the Road structure to fund out if it is surrounded by roads:

```
if (tile.up.has[Road]) {/*Do stuff*/} //tile.up gets another tile above it
```

Comment: @ChrisMartin I have done that, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case `isInstance` method of `t.runtimeClass` would work.

```
def has[StructureType <: UnfoundStructure]
  (implicit t: ClassTag[StructureType]): Boolean = {
  t.runtimeClass.isInstance(struct)
}
```

You don't have to check for `null` manually here – the result for `null` is `false` by specification.

Comment: Thanks, a neat solution!

Answer (score 0):

I have spent ages playing with this, until I read the output of my compiler. It turns out that the check in question is eliminated by erasure. To get around this I now have to do this, inelegant but it works:

```
def has[StructureType <: UnfoundStructure](implicit t: ClassTag[StructureType]):Boolean = {
if (struct == null)
  return false
if (struct.getClass==t.runtimeClass){ //Check if struct is the correct class, but get around erasure
  true
    }
    else false
}
```

If anyone has a better answer, I'd love to hear it!